# Android volley image loading causes heavy load on my server

Tags: android, android-volley

I'm using the volley library to load some .PNG images from my server. These images populate various cards in a listview. I've noticed that when a lot of my users are online at the same time, my server starts to get incredibly slow and the images fail to load. How can I fix this?

Comment: save the images in other place like amazon wen services or firebase,  But it have a cost, another solution maybe its compress de png, every image less of 300kb only get the thumbail.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should increase the perf of your server or improve the number of requests.

You could also consider using [Firebase Storage](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7puuTDSf3pk)

Answer (score 0):

1. Volley caches the images?
2. Lazy loading of the images by chunks like if app shows 10 cards on the screen then download 10-20 per each scroll...
3. Check the logic of vollets requests( jow and how many requesrs you are creating)